# Trying to Filter on 'Not tagged' AND 'Empty value' EC2 instances while using Boto3 in Lambda and then shut them down

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to figure out what the '**Not tagged**' AND '**Empty value**' fields are for EC2 instances when filtering them.  The function below works for Instances tagged **Owner** with a value of '**test**'.  However, the moment I try anything in place of '**test**' (*Null, None, Not tagged, Empty value, 0, etc...*) the function either returns every instance or the function return none of the instances.  I have gone through countless pages of documentation and any assistance is greatly appreciated.  If I cannot get this to work, my next step will be to use **Lambda**, **Tag** **Editor** and **Beautiful** **Soup** to locate **Specific** Un-Tagged and Empty Instances and shut them down.

```
import boto3
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

filters1 = [{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
    'Values': ['running']}]
base = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters1)

filters2 = [{'Name': 'tag:Owner',
    'Values': ['test']}]
instances = base.filter(Filters=filters2)

for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id)
RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]
ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=RunningInstances).stop()
```

Comment: Stuck in the same place. I'm also using ec2.instances.filter() and want to use a negation filter, basically getting all instances that DONT have a specific tag.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might use the concept of Events or reactive programming, instead of running such scan occasionally.

In AWS there are a few options to get relevant events to react to. It can be using [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) that is keeping track of your API calls, or [CloudWatch Events](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cloudwatch-events-track-and-respond-to-changes-to-your-aws-resources/) that is sending out events on changes in your infrastructure. But for this use case (tracking instances that are not tagged), you can use AWS Config Rules: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-config-rules-dynamic-compliance-checking-for-cloud-resources/

There is a template in AWS Config that is ready for you to configure your rule, and define the reaction to the event.

Comment: Thank you for the link you provided, its great!  One quick question, I only have 3 templates (encrypted-volumes, cloud-trail enabled, eip attached)  how do I get the other templates from your link?  I see other documentation referencing the "Required-Tags" template, but I do not see how to import or build that template.

Comment: There is a GitHub repository with a few examples. Here is for instance-type: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-rules/blob/master/python/ec2_desired_instance_type-triggered.py. More examples can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/03/new-aws-config-rules-repository-on-github-with-sample-rules/

Answer (score 0):

Just use describe_instances() to list all the tags, running state and build control from there.

```
ec2 = boto3.client("ec2")
reservations  = ec2.describe_instances()["Reservations"]
for each_item in reservations  :  
    for instance in each_item["Instances"]:
        print "{}  {} {}".format(instance["InstanceId"],  instance["State"]["Name"], instance["Tags"] )
```

Config Rules incur costs: $2 per active rule per month. So use it sparingly, you don't want to create too many redundant rules that get trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar situation. The best option i can see for now is.

- Tag all instances with a custom tag : `tagged-by:boto3`
- Filter all instances with this tag
- Run a loop through the instances to see if this is the only tag avilable
- if yes, delete the instance

I am still writing this in code, shall update the answer once its done.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out, if you choose the "(not tagged)" option in the Create Resource Group console screen, it lists nothing in the resulting resource group. From that point of view, it's just the same as using "(not tagged)" as one of the values in the AWS cli.

```
aws resource-groups create-group --name Non-Project-Linked-Resources --description "All resources NOT tagged with a ProjectNumber" --resource-query '{"Type":"TAG_FILTERS_1_0", "Query":"{\"ResourceTypeFilters\":[\"AWS::AllSupported\"],\"TagFilters\":[{\"Key\":\"ProjectNumber\",\"Values\":[\"\",\"(not tagged)\"]}]}"}'
```

has exactly the same effect as choosing ProjectNumber as the key and adding (empty value) and (not tagged) as the values. The consensus from all I have read is that server-side queries will not support searching for the absence of a tag.